# How to give the tomcat maximum memory physically available on the server?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

How to give the tomcat maximum memory physically available on the server?

I'm going to use a lot of caching in the webapp, so I do need a maximum RA-memory available to my app. To avoid possible OutOfMemory errors, etc.

Let's assume that server has N GB of RAM, and it's 64bit. I should run it under some options?

Additional related question:

How to see the memory left, or used by tomcat on the linux server?
If I run it under windows I can open the java console GUI app to see the level of used, available, free and so on by any java app... how to do the same on the linux console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way I know is adding -Xmx4096M into catalina.bat/catalina.sh to the place where the executable is being run. Of course, you replace 4096 with your physical memory in MB. For 32 bit, you can't go beyond 2 GB, at least in Windows. 
About seeing the used memory, you can type "ps aux | grep tomcat" in command line.

Comment: When you set -Xmx, be careful to leave enough for the rest of the system to use.  Otherwise, you'll get a lot of paging (disk I/O), especially during garbage collection.

Comment: @EdStaub so what is the best proportion between how much memory to take for app and how much leave to the rest of the system?? for example for 4G RAM server?

Comment: Check how much memory your system is using. "top" has some basic statistics. Depending on your environment I would leave at least 512 MB - 1 GB for the OS.